# Wordpress site shows "File not found." if opened through https

Tags: ssl, https

first time posting in this community, please correct me if this is not the right place to ask questions and seek help with WP. Thank you.

I have a setup consisting of: Virtualmin server on which is running Apache, with ~10 wordpress sites. Only on this one site, after installing SSL if I open the https://* i get the error "File not found.", nothing more. Whichever sub-url i try to open, whether it is https://*/wp-admin or whatever.

The http:// portion of the site is running without any issues and is fully (well, without SSL security) functional.

I have done this procedure on almost all of the other sites on the Virtualmin server, and all SSLs work fine. This is the only site with an issue.

So far, I've tried:

- Change the theme and deactivate all plugins, issue still remains.
- Used Really Simple SSL installer plugin, issue still remains.
- Changed all database entries for http://* to https://*, issue still remains.
- Compared all config files - apache as well as wordpress - to working sites, I can't seem to find an issue and differences.

Has anyone faced similar issues, or if anyone can guide me towards where to look for misconfigs in the WP site? Btw, the Certificate itself is fine, and it shows as active and enabled, just the content on the site doesn't load..

Comment: This does sound like an Apache config issue for me, yes. https is usually a separate virtual host, so you’ll need to make sure it has the correct document root and PHP configuration. Does /index.php work over HTTPS? (which should work even without rewrite rules set up.) Does /we-admin/? (which is also separate)